# Regular expression to debatch MT940 message

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I got a message with below structure, where message starts from tag :20: and ends at :86:. I want to write a regular expression to extract the all messages.
I would write a C# utility to extract each message and put it in ArrayList.

```
:20:160212-2359
:21:600******444
:28C:00001/00001
.
.
.
:86:DAILY SETTLEMENT /ENTRY-13 MAR
:62F:D160212GBP1229387,45
:64:D160212GBP1229387,45
:65:D120314GBP1229387,45
:65:D120315GBP1229387,45
:65:D120316GBP1229387,45
:65:D120317GBP1229387,45
:65:D120318GBP1229387,45
:86:FORWARD AVAILABLE FUNDS SHOW ITEMS KNOWN BUT NOT YET POSTED
some more comments in 86_2 segment 
this is line2
:20:160212-2359
:21:B***22
:25:60*****88
.
.
.
:86:/ENTRY-13 MAR TRF/REF 6*******64 /ORD/ some line here 
*********************** /BNF/ JO 88
:62F:C160212EUR13868931,00
:64:C160212EUR13868931,00
:65:C120314EUR13868931,00
:65:C120315EUR13791849,00
:65:C120316EUR13791849,00
:65:C120317EUR13791849,00
:65:C120318EUR13791849,00
:86:FORWARD AVAILABLE FUNDS SHOW ITEMS KNOWN BUT NOT YET POSTED
some more comments in 86_2 segment.
:20:160212-2359
:21:B****X
:25:6*************1
:28C:00001/00001
:86:STORE1 EUROPE B.V. /ENTRY-15 MAR RTS/REF 6*****6 RTS 
SWEPT FROM 9999 1**** XX***********BILLING CHARGES - 
28FEB12 TRF/REF 6641XXX43799053 /ITEMCNT/004 /BNF/ /ITEMCNT/004 
BILLING CHARGES
:61:1203130313DR10000000,00****288//6*****6
:86:STORE1 CNRTY SRL /ENTRY-13 MAR CLG/REF 66**********6
:61:1*****000,00NT*****9846//6******74
:86:NAME /ENTRY-13 MAR CLG/REF 6******4 LA C****R 
**** CASH DEPOSIT STORE1
:61:1203150315DR48531,00NCHGBILLING CHARGES//6641XXX43799053
:86:BILLING CHARGES - 28FEB12 /ENTRY-15 MAR TRF/REF 
66******53 /ITEMCNT/004
:62F:C160212EUR0,00
:64:C160212EUR0,00
:65:C120314EUR0,00
:65:C120315EUR0,00
:65:C120316EUR0,00
:65:C120317EUR0,00
:65:C120318EUR0,00
:86:FORWARD AVAILABLE FUNDS SHOW ITEMS KNOWN BUT NOT YET POSTED
{newline}
```

Actual values are replaced with '*' character.

Thanks
Dhiraj Bhavsar

Comment: @Trim007: My apologies, earlier I forgot to mention that segment :86: repeats in a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
:20:(.*?):86:
```

in code

```
/:20:(.*?):86:/gs
```

https://regex101.com/r/dW4zS3/1

`.*?` matches any character between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed